# Can I plug imaginary unit to solve partial fraction?

Tags: complex-numbers, partial-fractions

for example, I have partial fraction to solve:

$$
1/(x^2+1)(x^2+4)=A/(x^2+1)+B/(x^2+4)\
$$

then I need to solve 
$$
1=A(x^2+4)+B(x^2+1)
$$

Can I plug x=i and 2i so that I can get the value of A and B directly?

Is there any logical error to do that?

Comment: I believe your answer should take the form $$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4} $$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Example_2

Comment: Yes you can, although that is unnecessary if you note that the right side and left side are functions of $x^2$, which you can replace by $t$.

Comment: Since $1=A(x^2+4)+B(x^2+1)$ holds for any $x$, you can (or even must) do it if you don't change $x^2$ to $t$.

Answer (score 0):

If it's meant for integration, it's easier to put $x^2=y$

$$\dfrac1{(y+1)(y^2+1)}=\dfrac A{1+y}+\dfrac{By+C}{1+y^2}$$

$$\iff1=A(1+y^2)+(By+C)(1+y)$$

$A+B=B+C=0,C+A=1\implies-B=C=A=\dfrac12$

Can you take it from here?